# Update List Elements after creating a form

Tags: list, custom-form, item

Created a list.  Needed to modify certain input field to show mandatory (highlighted cell in red).  This had to be done in customize form.  Am I correct in finding that once a form has been created, all updates to the list for mat can no longer be made using List Settings?
For example, after form was created, I added a column using list settings.  While it shows up ion the main list screen, it does not show up when I click "Create new Item"

What I have to do is go back  to customize form and add it in using "Add new field", however when I do this I cannot get it to format correctly like the other field on the input screen.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, unfortunately this is normal behavior. Only the default OOTB forms will pick up the change to the list. What I usually do is after I've added the new column to the list, I'll create a new 'edit' form. Then you can open it up and copy the newly added table row for the column you recently added. Copy this into your real custom form you're using.